# Connect container created with docker-compose to another one created with docker run

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have the following container created with docker-compose (php:7.2.20-apache):

```
version: "3"
services
  php72:
    build:
     context: .
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
```

And I have the following container created with docker run:

```
docker run --name mysql5 -p 3306:3306 -v mysql5-data:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:5.7.27
```

I can connect to the mysql with MySQL Workbench, but my applications in the first container (php7 created with docker-compose) can't connect to the database with same connection credentials.

How to solve this?

PS: It`s a test of a dev environment in MacOs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manage a user-defined bridge for them to communicate with each other, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#manage-a-user-defined-bridge), detail as next:

**1. Create a user-define bridge**

```
$ docker network create my-net
```

**2. Link mysql container to this network**

```
$ docker run --name mysql5 -p 3306:3306 -v mysql5-data:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:5.7.27
$ docker network connect my-net mysql5
```

**3. Configure `docker-compose` to use the network**

```
version: "3"
services
  php72:
    build:
     context: .
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-net
```

Then, from [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge):

> User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between containers.

You can visit each other with service name or container name.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you use the correct address in php:7.2.20-apache container for the database as your MySQL Workbench most likely use different ip address (e.g. 127.0.0.1) than the php:7.2.20-apache container (e.g. 172.19.0.1)

Make sure the containers are on same network by listing your networks with

```
docker network ls
```

And if they are not, connect them to same one with

```
docker network connect
```

Usage:  docker network connect [OPTIONS] NETWORK CONTAINER
(See 'docker network connect --help' for more info.)

You can get more info about each network with command

```
docker network inspect
```

Usage:  docker network inspect [OPTIONS] NETWORK [NETWORK...]